# Keep value of function and button after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function(){
var $btn = $('#sendPush');
$btn.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('disabled', 'disabled').html("Sent");        
    $("#countdownOne").countdown360({
        radius      : 40,
        seconds     : 10,
        fontColor   : '#FFFFFF',
        autostart   : false,
        onComplete  : function () { $("#countdownOne").fadeOut();}
    }).start();
    setTimeout(function () {
            $this.removeAttr('disabled').html('Send Now');
        }, 10);  
    });
});
```

I want to countdown function still counting down and button Send Now to stay disabled after page refresh. I've included this in script https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie . Thanks.

Comment: Since you have included cookie plugin what problems are you having storing state using cookies? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, I've tried but no success, this is my first time dealing with cookies

Comment: Don't know that plugin.... what does `radius` refer to? Minutes? You will likely need to store `Date` when button is clicked and do some math on page reload to figure out difference between page load date and current date is before initializing plugin. Then clear cookie when timer completes

Comment: no,radius is just the size of countdown timer, I've also included javascript file of this timer at top of the code <script src="../js/jquery.countdown360.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: Provide link to plugin API docs. If you can't access the `current` value in the plugin will have to either modify plugin or find a different one that you can

Comment: https://github.com/johnschult/jquery.countdown360

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JavaScript cookie library: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Here is some code that does what you're asking for: http://jsfiddle.net/xf4at72w/16/

The countdown timer you're looking at doesn't have a few key features. 1) It doesn't let you specify the total seconds versus start seconds. 2) It doesn't let you update after starting. You could fork the JavaScript library and add the API methods you need...

Here is the method that starts the countdown and records the start time in a cookie:

```
$('#start').click(function(){
    // Record current time as JavaScript ticks
    Cookies.set('timer', (new Date()).getTime(), { expires: 7 });

    countdown = $("#countdown").countdown360({
        radius: 40,
        seconds: 20,
        label: ['sec', 'secs'],
        fontColor: '#FFFFFF',
        autostart: false,
        onComplete: function () {
            Cookies.set('timer', null);
            console.log('done');
        }
    });
    countdown.start();
});
```

Here is the code that reads the cookie and starts the timer after the web browser is refreshed...

```
if(+Cookies.get('timer') > 0) {
    // Read the start time as JavaScript ticks
    var start = new Date(+Cookies.get('timer'));
    var now = new Date();
    var seconds = getSeconds(now, start);
    seconds = 20 - seconds;
    if(seconds > 0) {
        countdown = $("#countdown").countdown360({
            radius: 40,
            seconds: seconds,
            label: ['sec', 'secs'],
            fontColor: '#FFFFFF',
            autostart: false,
            onComplete: function () {
                Cookies.set('timer', null);
                console.log('done');
            }
        });
        countdown.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've downloaded the js-cookie and I've included it inside,copy the whole code but it's not working,after refreshing everything stays the same...real pain in the a**

Comment: I've copied the whole code from Sam, changed the id's of button and div (#start and #countdown) and added this lines in javascript     <script src="../js/js-cookie-master/src/js.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.countdown360.min.js"</script>

Comment: Please update your question with your JavaScript code